# Fancybox not closing after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

I'm having trouble closing my fancy box in some cases after an ajax call.

```
 $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    function(){$.fancybox.close()};
 });

 $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $("a#load_gif").trigger('click');
 });
```

Here's my code handling the fancy box. So my problem is that if the ajax call is very brief and fast the box doesn't close, however if the call is longer it closes automatically as it should.

I have found a fix which goes along the line of this

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){$.fancybox.close()},500);
});
```

But honestly that solution is not good looking. What can I do to make the fancy box close even if the ajax call is returned very fast? The length of the ajax call is variable depending on the number of rows it has to fetch.

Any help and/or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have a race condition and maybe the fancybox isn't finished being created and doesn't have it's close function defined yet when your AJAX call is attempting to fire off that close function.

I recommend a 2 step process that triggers the fancybox to close. Create 2 global variables `ajaxStop = false;` and `fancyboxDone = false;`

create a function like:

```
function closeFancyBox(){
    if(ajaxStop && fancyboxDone){
        $.fancybox.close();
        ajaxStop = fancyboxDone = false;
    }
}
```

Then change your ajax stop to :

```
 $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    function(){
      ajaxStop = true;
      closeFancyBox()
    };
 });
```

And finally add an onComplete function to your fancybox that does the same as the ajax Stop but sets `fancyboxDone = true` instead of `ajaxStop`.

So now no matter which one finishes first and second they will be able to check on each other's status and fire the close appropriately.

Comment: Your function is like magic! It's working very well. A great and clean fix. Thank you.

Comment: "Your function is like magic!" - haha, best response I've gotten on SO so far.

Comment: Well, I had been searching long and large prior to posting this question so I was very happy to see an answer as clean and clear as this one haha.