# All AJAX async Requests completed event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a nested ajax requests. The first request returns a list with devices, for each device i do another ajax request to fetch more data. When the nested request is a success i'm appending the data to a `<table>`.

I need some kind of event that tells me when all requests are complete. How can i do this? See my code below

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Content("~/Service/listAllDevices")',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.devices.device, function (index, value) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Content("~/Service/listLokationLabelsForDevice")' + '?uuid=' + value.uuid,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data3) {
                    //Append to table
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: why dont you use single ajax call to the server which returns the whole data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use promises and `$.when()` to see when all your ajax calls have completed like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Content("~/Service/listAllDevices")',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var promises = [];
        $.each(data.devices.device, function (index, value) {
            promises.push($.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Content("~/Service/listLokationLabelsForDevice")' + '?uuid=' +
                    value.uuid,
                dataType: 'json',
            }));
        });
        $.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
            // all ajax results are done here
            // results from each ajax call are in order in
            // arguments[0], arguments[1], ...
            // you can now append them all to the table
        });
    }
});
```

The basic idea is that you collect the returned promise from each ajax call into an array.  You then use jQuery's `$.when` to have jQuery tell you when all those promises are resolved and to collect all the returned results from them and to keep all the data in the order you requested it in.  Then, when the `.done()` callback from `$.when()` is called, all the data is available and you can process it all at once, in order.

Note, I've also removed the success handler from the inner ajax call since you can process all the results in the `.done()` handler.

Answer (score 0):

The event you're looking for is `ajaxStop`.

```
$(document).on('ajaxStop', function() {
    //do something
});
```

Reference:

```
- http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstop/
```

Comment: This callback will be invoke after you finish every ajax, so it´s not what he is looking. he is looking when the "last" ajax call is finish

Comment: Not so. It is invoked after all registered requests have completed. ALL --- read the docs again. Do not mistake it with 'ajaxComplete'!

Comment: "Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery checks whether there are any other outstanding Ajax requests." Fair enough, but still I believe that there´re a potencial risk of race conditions

Comment: "**Description:** Register a handler to be called when all Ajax requests have completed. This is an Ajax Event." I use this event everyday and I know what ALL means. It's unfortunate that you for some reason you chose to read into the docs.

Comment: Take a look of this case here on StackOverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688176/fancybox-not-closing-after-ajax-call  By the way, was just an opinion take it easy. I did not vote negative you answer if is that what you tihnk